# In Autofac, how do I replace the default registration with a decorator?

Tags: c#, autofac

I ran in to some unexpected behaviour in Autofac (v4.4.0, .NET 4.6.1), which I feel may be a bug.

From the [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations):

> #### Default Registrations
>
> If more than one component exposes the same service, **Autofac will use the last registered component as the default provider of that service**:

e.g. If I do this:

```
    builder.RegisterType<FooOne>().As<IFoo>();
    // Next line replaces default IFoo implementation
    builder.RegisterType<FooTwo>().As<IFoo>();
```

I expect (and get) an instance of `FooTwo` when I resolve `IFoo` from the container.

However, if I have already registered an `IFoo`, and I use the `RegisterDecorator<T>` function to register a decorator of `IFoo`, it *does not* replace the default registration of `IFoo`. e.g:

```
    // Register FooOne directly
    builder.RegisterType<FooOne>().As<IFoo>(); // (1)
    // Now set up a decorator
    builder.RegisterType<FooOne>().Named<IFoo>("foo");
    builder.RegisterDecorator<IFoo>((c, inner) =>
      new DecoratorFoo(inner), fromKey: "foo");
```

Will resolve `IFoo` as an ***undecorated*** `FooOne`. This feels inconsistent to me; a violation of the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

You might claim that I shouldn't have line (1) at all (and the code works correctly without it) - but it's an accepted idiom (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754702/override-autofac-registration-with-plugin?rq=1)) to use a plug-in to replace registrations.

In my case, this bug manisfested in a fairly large codebase where the wrapped type was already registered by a convention and, now needing to be decorated, requires a significant re-think of how registration is done.

A Gist suitable for LINQPad demonstrating the issue is [here](https://gist.github.com/james-world/571c11b64f28baa6e27a44b818787ac3).

Is there any design reason for the observed behaviour that I am missing? Is there a way to have the decorator registration replace the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see open issue about your problem [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/529). In discussion there you can find reasoning behind this behavior. They are trying to fix this as I understand, but it turns out it is not quite trivial because of inner workings of autofac.

Meanwhile as a workaround you can register your decorator like this:

```
builder.Register((cnt, parameters) => new DecoratorFoo(cnt.ResolveNamed<IFoo>("foo", parameters))).As<IFoo>();
```

This will also fix another issue\bug (mentioned in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43141251/5311735)) which you might experience (or not) later, related to the fact decorator will not propagate parameters forward to decorated object.